# Express symbolic equation of KL Divergence between multivariate distribution succinctly in matrix form using Mathematica

Tags: matrix, probability-or-statistics

I would like to express the KL Divergence between 2 multi-variate Gaussian distributions in matrix form. I am able to compute the symbolic form but it essentially gives the output fully simplified down to the individual scalars. Is there a way for Mathematica to help convert that to a more readable matrix form like the form in Section 9 [here](https://stanford.edu/%7Ejduchi/projects/general_notes.pdf)? For example, in general, could Mathematica just rewrite the equation to collect variables in a way that the matrix form is apparent? Is there a way to specify the structure of variables?

```
\[CapitalSigma] = {{Subscript[\[Sigma], 
      1]^2, \[Rho] Subscript[\[Sigma], 1] Subscript[\[Sigma], 
      2]}, {\[Rho] Subscript[\[Sigma], 1] Subscript[\[Sigma], 2], 
    Subscript[\[Sigma], 2]^2}};

distV = MultinormalDistribution[{Subscript[\[Mu], 1], 
           Subscript[\[Mu], 2]}, \[CapitalSigma]]
        
        
distW = MultinormalDistribution[{Subscript[\[Mu], 3], 
           Subscript[\[Mu], 4]}, \[CapitalSigma]]

FullSimplify[
 ResourceFunction["KullbackLeiblerDivergence"][distV, distW]]
```

$KL(distV, distW)= -\frac{-2 \left(\mu _1-\mu _3\right) \left(\mu _2-\mu _4\right) \rho  \sigma _2 \sigma _1+\left(\mu _2-\mu _4\right){}^2 \sigma _1^2+\left(\mu _1-\mu _3\right){}^2 \sigma _2^2}{2 \left(\rho ^2-1\right) \sigma _1^2 \sigma _2^2}$

I would like the above output simplified so that the matrix form is obvious.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Questions should be self-contained. Please copy and paste your code here, together with an example of the output you would like. See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951).

Comment: Thank you! I have done this.

Comment: Thank you! I have done this.